# Jquery append exceed max height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a jquery code which loop through a list of object and append html to a table.However i already set the max height of the parent/table. The table row still exceed the parent.

record should stop at the red line show in the picture and a scroll bar should appear.

anyone can help?

**Jquery**

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
     $('#dataTable').append("<tr><td>" + i + '</td><td>' + item.name+ '</td><td>' + item.English + '</td><td>' + item.Quantity + '</td><td>' + item.Brand + '</td></tr>')
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:700px;">
   <div class="panel-heading">Records</div>
   <div class="panel-body" style="max-height:700px; z-index:5;">
      <table id="dataTable" class="table" style="height:700px;overflow:auto;">
         <tr>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to re-render the data table?

Comment: no. i want a scroll bar to appear after record 14/15 onwards.I already set `over-flow:auto` but it is not working

Comment: @MVCnewbie so you want a scroll or do you want the height to increase

Comment: i want a scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following style cases from table tag `height:700px;overflow:auto;` and apply `overflow:auto;` style case in the class `.panel-body`. `overflow:auto;` style case won't work in table tag.

Comment: arg thanks so much. But i though it should work also?